# nesting backquote and ` in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

There seems to be some difference between short backquote and long backquote.

```
(let ((x 123))
  (dolist (res (list `(a `(b ,x))
                     `(a (backquote (b ,x)))
                     (backquote (a (backquote (b ,x))))
                     (backquote (a `(b ,x)))))
    (print res)))
```

Output:

```
(a (\` (b (\, x))))

(a (backquote (b 123)))

(a (backquote (b 123)))

(a (\` (b (\, x))))
```

Why does it behave differently as to x? Not even sure which two of the four results are supposed to be the surprising results.

Comment: those are actually backtick

Comment: I think it is a bug in `backquote.el`. See my comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a bug or a feature, mainly because I'm not sure if a elisp programmer is allowed/good practice to use the `backquote` function, or it is just a convenient way of defining the function. The correct output is the first (and fourth) output. Looking at the code for `backquote` (in `backquote.el`) it is clear that any `backquote` inside either a ` or `backquote` is not properly expanded. The relevant code for this is:

```
   ((eq (car s) backquote-backquote-symbol)
      (backquote-delay-process s (1+ level)))
```

where `backquote-backquote-symbol` is defined before as '\` (quote-backslash-backtick). There are several ways of treating this error, but the line could be then:

```
   ((or (eq (car s) backquote-backquote-symbol)
        (eq (car s) 'backquote))
      (backquote-delay-process s (1+ level)))
```

(or using any other variable for specifying the backquote unaliased symbol).

**EDIT**: Looking at it more closely, there is another place where you have to add that test too, but this includes reporting a patch. I'll see how do I do it. With that change:

```
ELISP> (macroexpand-all `(a (backquote (b ,x))))
(a
 (list 'b x))
ELISP> (macroexpand-all `(a `(b ,x)))
(a
 (list 'b x))
```